# set truststore for kusto sink connector

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I want to set a specified truststore file and password for kusto sink connector.
Which parameters should I use?
Seems the connector will use the truststore file under jre by default, right?

Thanks,

I want to set a specified truststore file and password for kusto sink connector.

Answer (score 0):

the qusto sing connectors uses the default Java truststore, If you want to set a specified trust store file and password for the Kusto Sink Connector,follow the sample config snip below.

```html
name=my-kusto-sink-connector
connector.class=com.microsoft.azure.kusto.kafka.connect.sink.KustoSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=my-topic
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
kusto.tables.mapping=my-table:my-topic
kusto.ingestion.properties.file=path/to/ingestion/properties/file
kusto.authentication.clientId=myClientId
kusto.authentication.clientKey=myClientKey
kusto.authentication.authority=myAuthority
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/your/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=yourTruststorePassword
```

Comment: Is this sorted? Tom